# Print external javascript file contents on page

Tags: javascript

I have a js file that stores google analytics data. I am hard coding them on all the pages. For a change in one value, I have to make changes on 1000+ pages, as I am hard coding it.

Below is my google code.

```
//Google Tracking Code  Part 01

    var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");

    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));

//Google Tracking Code  Part 02 

    try {
    var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("xx-12345678-12");
    pageTracker._trackPageview();
    } catch (err) {

    }
```

So I have created an external JavaScript file called googleAnalytics.js, where the above code would exist, so that when I make a change, it automatically gets reflected on all the pages.

Is there a javascript code that prints this external file codes on all the pages (i.e the source and not text) by reading the contents from the external file ??

Comment: I've googled and have founded something like this :) http://webdesign.about.com/od/javascript/ht/htjsincludehtm.htm
Hope this will provide some help.

Comment: But that is writing HTML, whereas I have a js that has javascript codes. So is that possible ? - @Mr.TK

Comment: The google analytic code has to be printed on page. I have made it an external file just to know, whether is there any javascript method that it can be fetched from there and printed when we view the source. I don't mind removing it. - @CBroe

Comment: As I have mentioned that I have to hard code the code, I have to make changes to 1000+ pages. So I have created an external js, but for google analytics, that does not make a proper analysis unless it is seen on page. I have created this external file to know whether it can be called on page via a javascript method. If there is another way, I dont need the external file, as this would reflect twice, so I shall remove it, if I get another method to print that on page. - @CBroe

Comment: The google analytic code is same for all the pages, but, when there is any change in the code, due to an extra addition of other codes, I have to hard code it (find and replace it) on thousands of pages. That takes me a lot of time. So if at all, it can be done via JavaScript, I would like to know that method. - @CBroe

Comment: So You are telling us that You cannot paste it into bottom of the &lt;body&gt; into footer? :) 
Or maybe You are using same google analytics code on many sites?? If yes, then why to do such a cruel thing?? :D

Comment: No no .. I am not using the same analytics code on many sites. I am just making a change to more than 1000+ pages on the same website, so I need a JavaScript solution to make sure that the code gets reflected on all the pages, provided, it is stored at one place, so that, when, any change does takes place, I just have to make change at one place and it gets reflected on all the pages .. That is the simplest way I can explain what I am looking for. So nothing cruel about it.. I hope your perception is clear now .. - @Mr.TK

Comment: Mr @CBroe - I have repeatedly said that I have done that thing already. I have created an external file and it works fine, but .. BUT .. BUT .. Google Analytics code is the only code that needs to come on page rather than externally, as it will give a wrong analysis .. So, the src works for me technically, but analytically, google does not give me accurate data .. So, as I have mentioned earlier also, I have to hard code it on 1000+ pages to make that work on page .. Comment continued below ..

Comment: Comment continued from above .. And, I want to know, if, at all, there is a javascript method, with which, I shall REMOVE the external link and get a method, where, the script is stored and called and that gets print when you check "View source". so that my hard coding efforts are reduced. I assume that even you know the basics of ENGLISH Language that I have mentioned here and now you are CRYSTAL CLEAR with my Scenario Mr @CBroe